# ggplot graph in R based on many variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data sets, `d1` and `d2` in csv files. Each data has 6 columns. I managed to combine them  by `melt` command and graph them together in `ggplot`. After I have added one extra column which is another variable the graph would depend on, I couldn't get the required graph. Provided sample of the dataset and my code.

The dataset **after** using `melt` and `reshape` package:

```
initi A   B       C     D    E   L1
0.005 1 23.7      1.0  1.0  24.7 d2
0.005 2 31.2      2.0  2.1  31.2 d2
0.005 3 35.8      3.1  3.2  35.6 d2
 1    1 6.2       1.0  1.0  6.2  d1
 1    2 10.1      2.0  2.1  7.0  d1
 1    3 11.2      3.0  3.5  7.0  d1
 2    1 14.2      8.0 14.3  5.2  d1
 2    2 15.9      7.0 13.0  5.5  d1
 2    3 16.0      6.2 12.4  5.8  d1
```

I need to graph `A` in the `X-axis` and `B` in the `Y-axis`. The `initi` value will represent each graph. In other words, it will be in the legend. For `d1`, I need to plot the results between `A` and `B`. For `d2` I want to plot two graphs where the first graph when the `initi = 1` and the second for `initi = 2`. All of the graphs for `d1` and `d2` are between `A` and `B` and combined in graph. The total in this case 3 lines combined in one graph.
I managed to graph `d1` and `d2` before I have added the `initi` column. Now I struggling. Below is my code:

```
 dlist <- list(d1 =data1 ,d2 = data2) 
 reshaped_data <- melt(dlist, id.vars = c('initi','A','B','C','D','E')) 
 graph_AB<-ggplot(reshaped_data,aes(x = A, y = B, colour = initi)) +  
     geom_point(size = 5)+
     geom_line() +
     ggtitle("DATA1 vs DATA2")
```

The above code is close to what I want ...Except that the lines are connected in strange way. I should get each pattern for "initi" as one line. Plus the legend is not showing each value of 'initi'

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what you want. So, I'll here write here in the comment to see if it is before I write as answer: Does this work? `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = A, y = B, colour=factor(initi))) + geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_grid( . ~ L1)`

Comment: Yes it did sometheing close to what I want.It produced two graphs next each other. For d1 it produced one graph with d1 results only (A VS B). In graph 2, d2 results!!!?. Both graphs under one title and one legend ??? I want to combine them ??

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow... Could you please explain again (by editing your post what you want to plot)?

Comment: For `d2` there is no `initi=1` at all in the data you've shown.

Comment: Yes the initi value is changing. so with d1, we have only one initi value. however, in d2 I have more initi values and for the sake of simplifying the example I put only two. Check the update.

Comment: There is no change in the data with your edit. Which edit do you mean?

Comment: Do you want to facet based on `L1` or `initi`? It is not quite clear.. And what do you mean `initi` is changing?

Comment: L1 represents the data (d1 or d2) and Initi is a value I used for results. If you check column A, it is from 1-to-3 for d1 and d2 while 'initi' is changing for each new set of A.

Comment: No I have only d1 and d2 .... For d2 I have around 6 initi values. For d1 I have only one Initi value. if you run run the code (I update the code in the question) you will understand what want?

Comment: Please edit your data so there is no `d3`. Better yet, paste the output of `reshaped_data` so I can copy/paste your data.

Comment: Check the updated data

Comment: Thank you for dput command I will use it for future. Adding "group" does not change anything from what I have provided in the question.????

Comment: with geom_point it is acceptable... However, with lines it is not

Answer (score 0):

You say you want two graphs, one for when `initi` is 1 and another for when it is 2, but it also takes the value 0.005. You need to subset your data first if you want to omit the `0.005` level.

In ggplot2, multiple graphs are called "facets", and since your facets depend on one variable, the command you want is `facet_wrap()`. (You'd use `facet_grid` if your facets depended on 2 variables.) Facets should be on factors, so we'll make sure `initi` is a factor

```
reshaped_data$initi <- factor(reshaped_data$initi)
```

then just add `+ facet_wrap(~ initi)` to your ggplot.

EDIT: 
If you want just one graph, try

```
graph_AB<-ggplot(reshaped_data,aes(x = A, y = B, colour = initi, group = L1)) +  
    geom_point(size = 5)+
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle("DATA1 vs DATA2")

graph_AB
```

In the future, post data using `dput`. For example, if you do `dput(reshaped_data)` and paste it into your question, the output will be this:

```
    structure(list(initi = c(0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2), A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), B = c(23.7, 31.2, 
35.8, 6.2, 10.1, 11.2, 14.2, 15.9, 16), C = c(1, 2, 3.1, 1, 2, 
3, 8, 7, 6.2), D = c(1, 2.1, 3.2, 1, 2.1, 3.5, 14.3, 13, 12.4
), E = c(24.7, 31.2, 35.6, 6.2, 7, 7, 5.2, 5.5, 5.8), L1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("d1", "d2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("initi", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "L1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

which anyone can paste into R and use easily.

Comment: I thought `initi`, since it has to be in legend, should be `colour` and the facetting should be on `L1`...

Comment: @Arun Hmm, maybe. Based on "The initi value will represent each graph" I assumed the goal was to facet on that, but it's pretty confusing. Maybe "will represent" should be "will be present in", in which case I'm all wrong.

Comment: What I want exactly to plot is one graph to compare d1 and d2 results (A and B) with respect to the change of 'initi'. I tried something like :'ggplot(df,aes(x = A, y = B, colour = initi,shape=L1))' it worked, but it doesn't show me the legend correctly.

Comment: @shujaa I think I need facet_grid (initi and L1 both changing)

Comment: Could you provide the full ggplot command for your suggestion.

Comment: I managed to use your suggestions. It's not what I want ? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
dlist <- list(d1 =data1 ,d2 = data2) 
reshaped_data <- melt(dlist, id.vars = c('initi','A','B','C','D','E')) 
graph_AB<-ggplot(reshaped_data,aes(x = A, y = B, colour = initi)) +  
geom_point(size = 5)+
ggtitle("DATA1 vs DATA2") 
print(graph_AB)
```

I just removed geom_line from original question !